# query to select from two tables on symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1

I am learning symfony framework. Now I am getting all data from mysql table `orders` this way:

> ```
> $c = new Criteria();
> $this->items = OrdersPeer::doSelect($c);
> ```

Also I have other table `orders_complete`. How can I get data from tables `orders` and `orders_complete`?

I want to do this query:

> `SELECT * FROM orders, orders_complete WHERE orders.id =
>   orders_complete.id`

Comment: You need to make sure there is a foreign key relationship between the 2 tables. Propel will not allow joins on unrelated tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember right, with propel you should be able to do something like :

`$c = new Criteria();
    $orders = OrdersPeer::doSelect($c);
    foreach($orders as $order) {
        $complete = $order->getOrderCompletes();
        // do something with $order and $complete ...
    }`

This providing that you have defined the two tables relationship within your schema file... 
Do check the propel documentation regarding this : http://propelorm.org/documentation/04-relationships.html#using-relationships-in-a-query